# How to connect two vagrant ubuntu box with ssh

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to connect two ubuntu vagrant boxes using ssh. My aim is to simulate on local machine communication between vm-box1 to vm-box2 using Python Fabric library, for that I have to create private network using static ip address. vm-box1 is the main box from where I want to access vm-box2 using Fabric library. To make my Fabric connection work I need to setup a network where I can use ssh. I tried following method to set a static ip address in private network.

I added following line in my box2 Vagrantfile

`config.vm.network "private_network", :ip => "192.168.1.111", :netmask => "255.255.255.0"`

And did vagrant up. Upon spinning up the machine successfully and later doing ifconfig could see IPv4 is assigned with static ip address:

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::45:2ff:fe5a:c0a3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:45:02:5a:c0:a3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3166  bytes 527516 (527.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1945  bytes 267522 (267.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feee:c657  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:ee:c6:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17  bytes 1326 (1.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 26  bytes 2312 (2.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26  bytes 2312 (2.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And from my windows ipconfig output:

```
Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5f0:a3f4:e833:9aec%25
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.203
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

This is my Vagrantfile config:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
    
    config.vm.network "private_network", :ip => "192.168.1.111", :netmask => "255.255.255.0"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 7072 
    config.vm.synced_folder "", "/home/", :owner=>"vagrant", :group=>"vagrant", :mount_options=>["dmode=777","fmode=666"]
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus = 2
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
    end
end
```

Now when I try to ping 192.168.1.111 I get following output on terminal:

Pinging `192.168.1.111` with 32 bytes of data:

```
Reply from 192.168.1.1: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

After researching on the internet I found out that adding these `gateway4` and `nameservers` addresses into /etc/netplan/50-vagrant.yml file will make visible to my host network.

```
gateway4: 198.168.1.1
nameservers: 
  addresses: [198.168.1.1,8.8.8.8]
```

After applying netplan I got disconnected with ssh session and couldn't connect back to my vm-box2 machine again. I am using Windows 10 as a host and Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

I am new to multi-node vm machine networking. Any guidance on how to properly setup vm-machines in network would be great.